# Proof of the reciprocal of all semiprimes diverging?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers, divergent-series, semiprimes

$$\sum_{\text{semi-primes}}\frac{1}{s}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}\cdots$$

I almost positive that this sum diverges, but I would really like to see a very thorough proof. Thank you.

Comment: It diverges at a rate of $~\displaystyle\sum_{s<n}\frac1s\simeq\frac{\ln^2\ln n}2+\frac15$

Comment: @Lucian Any reference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a subseries is $$ \frac{1}{2} \left(  \frac{1}{2} +   \frac{1}{3} +   \frac{1}{5} +   \frac{1}{7} +   \frac{1}{11} +  \right)  $$

Answer (score 1):

If you look just at the terms with even denominators you have half the sum of the reciprocals of the primes.

Curiously enough, for each prime $p$ the terms with denominator a multiple of $p$ give $1/p$ times the (infinite) sum of the reciprocals of the primes. Of course these subseries overlap. Euler could probably make something of this.

Comment: Clearly the sum is just $\tfrac12 (P(1)^2 + P(2))$ where $P(s)$ is the prime zeta function.  But I seem to recall that the singularity at $s=1$ is an essential one, so not sure how much Euler would have gotten out of that divergent series :).